# How to solve code duplication in this example where I introduce inheritance to actually solve code duplication

Tags: java, android, inheritance, dry

Suppose I have an App with different `Scenes`. Each Scene has a layout that is build up by a number of `ScreenElement`s, e.g., rectangular boxes that will be drawn to the `Canvas`. For some `Scenes`, the same boxes will be used. Therefore, in view of DRY, I want to use inheritance.

What I want to do is to store the `ScreenElement`s in a `HashMap` (or ultimately an `EnumMap`) so that I can call on the `ScreenElement`s elsewhere in my code to change their attributes.

Here is what I came up with now...

Here is the basic layout:

```
Public class BasicLayout {
    private HashMap<String, ScreenElement> screenElements;

    public BasicLayout() {
        screenElements = new HashMap<>();
        screenElements.put("BACKGROUND", new ScreenElement(...));
        screenElements.put("BOXONE", new ScreenElement(...));
        screenElements.put("BOXTWO", new ScreenElement(...));
    }

    public HashMap<String, ScreenElement> getScreenElements() {
        return screenElements;
    }

    public ScreenElement getScreenElement(String elementName) {
        return screenElements.get(elementName);
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        for (ScreenElement screenElement: screenElements) {
            screenElement.draw(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

Then another layout could be something like:

```
Public class OtherLayout extends BasicLayout {      
    private HashMap<String, ScreenElement> screenElements;

    public OtherLayout() {
        screenElements = new HashMap<>(super.getScreenElements);
        screenElements.put("BOXTHREE", new ScreenElement(...));
        screenElements.put("BOXFOUR", new ScreenElement(...));
    }

    @Override
    public HashMap<String, ScreenElement> getScreenElements() {
        return screenElements;
    }

    @Override
    public ScreenElement getScreenElement(String elementName) {
        return screenElements.get(elementName);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        for (ScreenElement screenElement: screenElements) {
            screenElement.draw(canvas);
        }
}
```

**So the thing is that by solving code duplication (I no longer need to add BACKGROUND, BOXONE and BOXTWO in my `OtherLayout`), I introduce code duplication!**

I now need to duplicate the `getScreenElements`, `getScreenElement` and `draw` methods. In this case you need to override them, because if you don't, `getScreenElements`, for example, always return BACKGROUND, BOXONE and BOXTWO, even when you actually want BACKGROUND, BOXONE, BOXTWO, BOXTHREE and BOXFOUR (for example in the `Scene` that uses `OtherLayout'.

Hope this makes sense and that someone has an ingenious solution!

To clarify:

- At any time `BasicLayout` should have BACKGROUND, BOXONE and BOXTWO
- At any time `OtherLayout` should have BACKGROUND, BOXONE, BOXTWO,
  BOXTHREE and BOXFOUR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
public class BasicLayout {
    protected HashMap<String, ScreenElement> screenElements = new HashMap<>();

    public BasicLayout() 
    {
        screenElements.put("BACKGROUND", new ScreenElement(...));
        screenElements.put("BOXONE", new ScreenElement(...));
        screenElements.put("BOXTWO", new ScreenElement(...));
    }

    public HashMap<String, ScreenElement> getScreenElements() {
        return screenElements;
    }

    public ScreenElement getScreenElement(String elementName) {
        return screenElements.get(elementName);
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        for (ScreenElement screenElement: screenElements) {
            screenElement.draw(canvas);
        }
    }
}

public class OtherLayout extends BasicLayout {     
    public OtherLayout() {
        screenElements.put("BOXTHREE", new ScreenElement(...));
        screenElements.put("BOXFOUR", new ScreenElement(...));
    }
}
```

Comment: If you create a BasicLayout u have BACKGROUND, BOXONE and BOXTWO, if you create a OtherLayout you have BACKGROUND, BOXONE, BOXTWO, BOXTHREE, BOXFOUR.

Comment: What you mean by go back? If you create an instance of a subclass doesn't mean u create two instances, so there is no shared screenElements at all.

Comment: I refactored my code and it works like a charm! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think solving inheritance is a good choice for avoiding duplication. You always violate Liskov substitution principle is some settle way (in your case not so settle:)). And that leads to far bigger problems down the line.

And the second point inheritance should be used only to share behaviour not data.

I think in your case the delegation/composition is a better fit:

```
public OtherLayout() {
    screenElements = new HashMap<>();
    screenElements.putAll(new BasicLayout().getScreenElements());
    screenElements.put("BOXTHREE", new ScreenElement());
    screenElements.put("BOXFOUR", new ScreenElement());
}
```

Because from the looks of it the only thing that is common for the two classes are the elements in the source elements map.

And a more general note. Don't be afraid of duplication as much as the wrong abstraction. The quote from the pioneer of modern computer science (Edsger Dijkstra):

> The purpose of abstraction is not to be vague, but to create a new
>   semantic level in which one can be absolutely precise

Comment: You are right, I am primarily sharing data (and some behavior). In your solution, each different type of layout (I have not only `OtherLayout` but also `OtherLayout2`, `OtherLayout3`,...) needs its own `getters` and `draw` methods, right? You don't see that as a problem? Especially if you have many layouts? Meini's answer works nicely and the code is nice and concise.

Comment: The solution might look good in terms of numbers of lines but to me the intention is **not clear**. I like to look at the code and know what's going on immediately. That is why I said that inheritance is not to share data. Suddenly you have to follow this fuzzy logic of state mutation that now spans 2 classes. And the tree of class hierarchy tends to get bigger, with time, not smaller.

Comment: The solution proposed by @Meini is very clever. But in my opinion it is too clever for it's own good :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sample code, there only needs to be a single class which takes the elements it will be responsible for in the constructor.  For example:

```
public class Layout {
    private final Map<String, ScreenElement> screenElements;

    public Layout(Map<String, ScreenElement> screenElements) {
        this.screenElements = screenElements;
    }

    // other methods
}
```

From your example, somewhere in the code base would know to create a `BasicLayout` or `OtherLayout`.  Refactor that code and extract the map, and pass to the constructor.  For example:

```
 // in some method that knows when to create a `BasicLayout` or `OtherLayout`
 Map<String, ScreenElement> basicScreenElements = new HashMap<>();
 basicScreenElements .put("BACKGROUND", new ScreenElement(...));
 basicScreenElements .put("BOXONE", new ScreenElement(...));
 basicScreenElements .put("BOXTWO", new ScreenElement(...));
 Layout basicLayout = new Layout(basicScreenElements);

// ....
 Map<String, ScreenElement> otherScreenElements = new HashMap<>();
 otherScreenElements .put("BOXTHREE", new ScreenElement(...));
 otherScreenElements .put("BOXFOUR", new ScreenElement(...));
 Layout otherLayout = new Layout(otherScreenElements);
```

Comment: In your example, `otherLayout` does not contain BACKGROUND, BOXONE and BOXTWO. If you want this, you need to add them, which leads to code duplication.

Comment: The creation of a `ScreenElement` object could be moved to a factory class, or provide a `ScreenElement` copy constructor.